# Cocos2d / box2d project wont compile after project clean

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, compiler-errors, box2d

I have been building a project with cocos2d 2.0 and box2d, and after cleaning it, it completely breaks. 
The compiler stops after 30+ errors: "Too many errors committed, stopping now."

errors like: 
precompile prefix.pch: unknown typename 'NSUInteger'

any ideas?
what other information would help? (rookie here)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The problem came from a class named "Block". I renamed the class and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you added one or more Box2D header files to the prefix.pch without enclosing it in #ifdef __cplusplus therefore the compiler will try to compile them as regular C (Objective-C) files.

Here's a sample prefix.pch with Box2D headers included correctly:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
// objective-c headers go here, for example:
#import "cocos2d.h"
#endif // __OBJC__


#ifdef __cplusplus
// C++ header files go here, for example:
#import "Box2D.h"
#endif // __cplusplus
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. This did not work. The only solution I have found is to rebuild the project from a cocos2d/box2d template and copy/paste the code.